# How to use Checkbox in a View to create a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able from a view to check some elements selected from my database and displaid into a table in my view.
The idea is to build a list with elements' ids and use this list to print all selected element, so I tried to use checkbox to select or not each row of my table. Then I wanted to use a *link_to* to call a controller action with a parameter that contains the list of my ids as :

```
<%= link_to 'Printer', :controller => 'MyController', :action => 'MyAction', :element_list => mylistofelement %>
```

But I don't succeed to create `mylistofelement`.

How can I build such a list into the View and being able to have `mylistofelement` looks like `1,3,6,7,8` or an array, ... but something I can use as a parameter to work with into my controller action.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK! So this is one solution. I did this in rails 3.1.0rc2 btw.

So your view should look something like this

```
<%= form_tag 'display' %>
<% @artists.each do |artist| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= artist.name %></td>
   <td><%= artist.song %></td>
   <td><%= check_box("display", artist.id) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

<%= submit_tag 'Print' %>

<% end %>
```

This will post to 'display' in your current controller (I added it to routes.rb)
You can check in your rails server log window that it posts our values in the params

"display"=>{"1"=>"1", "2"=>"0", "3"=>"0"}

"1"=>"1" means artist.id=1 and the corresponding checkbox was checked.
"3"=>"0" artist.id = 3 checkbox unchecked

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
   def display
      @ids = []
      params[:display].each do |key,val|
         if val != "0"
           @ids << key
         end
      end

      render 'display'
   end
```

end

Just something i hacked togheter... Hope it helps!

Comment: @eldewall: no i have for sample table artists(id,name,song). I display the table content in a view formated as
<% for artist in @artists -%>
<td>artist.id</td><td>artist.name</td><td>artist.song</td> i want to create anew td with checkbox to select the rows i want to send to an action that will print the related information.

Comment: Ah your looking at making some kind of form and use the check_box_tag helper. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

Comment: At work at the moment, can give you some examples/tips to get you started later when i get back home!

Comment: Hello 
i follow your instruction but when i press Print buttom it is like nothing happen there is no trace
i created in the routes.rb file the entry  map.connect '/myurl', :controller => "controller_name", :action => "print"
is this OK can we exchange by email? 
Thanks for your help and advises.

Comment: What version of rails are you running?